# Removing focus on input using Bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to remove focus from an input so the user can read the content before entering any information. Does anyone know how to achieve this through Bootstrap? I've tried adjusting the CSS file but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `onfocus` is `onblur` you can force the blur with Javascript as shown in the example below. I don't think you can force blur without using Javascript.

Non Jquery:

```
document.getElementById("target").blur();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp

Jquery:

```
$( "#target" ).blur();
```

https://api.jquery.com/blur/